# How can I make XmlSerializer Deserialize tell me about typos on tag names

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I know that most of the time, the `Deserialize` method of `XmlSerializer` will complain if there's something wrong (for example, if there is a typo). However, I've found an example where it doesn't complain, when I would have expected it to; and I'd like to know if there's a way of being told about the problem.

The example code below contains 3 things: an good example which works as expected, and example which would complain (commented out) and an example which does not complain, which is the one I want to know how to tell that there is something wrong.

**Note:** I appreciate that one possible route would be XSD validation; but that really feels like a sledgehammer to crack what seems like a simpler problem. For example, if I was writing a deserializer which had unexpected data that it didn't know what to do with, I'd make my code complain about it.

I've used NUnit (NuGet package) for assertions; but you don't really need it, just comment out the `Assert` lines - you can see what I'm expecting.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using NUnit.Framework;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string goodExampleXml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><Example><Weathers><Weather>Sunny</Weather></Weathers></Example>";
        var goodExample = Load(goodExampleXml);
        Assert.That(goodExample, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(goodExample.Weathers, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(goodExample.Weathers, Has.Length.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(goodExample.Weathers.First(), Is.EqualTo(Weather.Sunny));

        string badExampleXmlWhichWillComplainXml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><Example><Weathers><Weather>Suny</Weather></Weathers></Example>";
        // var badExampleWhichWillComplain = Load(badExampleXmlWhichWillComplainXml); // this would complain, quite rightly, so I've commented it out

        string badExampleXmlWhichWillNotComplain = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?><Example><Weathers><Weathe>Sunny</Weathe></Weathers></Example>";
        var badExample = Load(badExampleXmlWhichWillNotComplain);
        Assert.That(badExample, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(badExample.Weathers, Is.Not.Null);
        // clearly, the following two assertions will fail because I mis-typed the tag name; but I want to know there has been a problem before this point.
        Assert.That(badExample.Weathers, Has.Length.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(badExample.Weathers.First(), Is.EqualTo(Weather.Sunny));
    }

    private static Example Load(string serialized)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialized);
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Example));
        using var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray, false);
        return (Example)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}

public enum Weather
{
    Sunny,
    Cloudy,
    Rainy,
    Windy,
    Stormy,
    Snowy,
}

public class Example
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1819:PropertiesShouldNotReturnArrays", Justification = "Serialized XML")]
    [XmlArray("Weathers")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Weather")]
    public Weather[] Weathers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: An xml file should always be validated when it generated and not when it is being used.  It is wrong to distribute a bad xml file.  You shouldn't be fixing errors with bad xml.  Just send it back to the people who created the file.  You should be using the sledgehammer to crack open the people who generated the file.

Comment: @jdweng *"An xml file should always be validated when it generated"* and *"Just send it back to the people who created the file"*... I'd love to... if only I had **known** that there were typos in the file; but they were being ignored by the deserializer.

Comment: What do you mean by typos?  If the deserialize is ignoring items then the c# classes are not matching the xml file.  So issue can be with the classes.  So inconsistencies between classes and xml will cause exceptions and other  will be ignored and data will be missing.  The best way of finding missing items is to deserialize and then serialize to a new xml file.  Then use Beyond compare to see difference in the two xml files.  I do not know if the typos are in the xml or the c# classes.  Do a comparison will help.

Comment: @jdweng *"What do you mean by typos?"* the example posted in the question demonstrates the typos: a typo in the name of the enum value will cause an exception (`badExampleXmlWhichWillComplainXml`) and a typo in the name of the tag won't (`badExampleXmlWhichWillNotComplain`). Regarding re-serializing and comparing... I want to detect this programmatically, rather than using a GUI application each time. Programmatic comparison of XML is non trivial due to namespaces and whitespace variations. This is why I was hoping there's some way I can make the Deserializer notify me of the issue.

Comment: I was referring to missing deserialization properties and not you posted example. Remove the XmlArray and XmlArrayItem is is not needed if they are enumerations.  Replace with [XlmElement()].  XmlArray and XmlArrayItem is only used when the xml has two tags and two classes in c#.  You have one property in your classes.  You have one xml tag Weather and an array Weather[] (more than one item).  So you use [XmlElement]

Comment: @jdweng I have tried what you suggested (fixing the typo in your comment) but it does not work - the deserialization which works in the question does not work with your change. The example is intentionally showing an array because that is the scenario where the problem is occurring. That property is an array, not a single value, because it can contain multiple instances of Enum values (for example, note that the enum is not marked with the "Flags" attribute). Since it is an array, there is a Tag for the collection of items, and then there is a tag for each individual item in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked at Microsoft's published source code for [XmlSerializer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs), it became apparent that there are events that you can subscribe to (which is what I was hoping for); but they aren't exposed on the `XmlSerializer` itself... you have to inject a struct containing them into the constructor.

So I've been able to modify the code from the question to have an event handler which gets called when an unknown node is encountered (which is exactly what I was after). You need one extra using, over the ones given in the question...

```
using System.Xml;
```

and then here is the modified "Load" method...

```
    private static Example Load(string serialized)
    {
        XmlDeserializationEvents events = new XmlDeserializationEvents();
        events.OnUnknownNode = (sender, e) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unknown Node: " + e.Name);

        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Example));
        using var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(serialized));
        return (Example)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader, events);
    }
```

So now I just need to do something more valuable than just write a line to the Debug output.

Note that more events are available, as described on the [XmlDeserializationEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmldeserializationevents?view=netcore-3.1) page, and I'll probably pay attention to each of them.

Answer (score 0):

I tested following and it works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                <Example>
                  <Weathers>Sunny</Weathers>
                  <Weathers>Cloudy</Weathers>
                  <Weathers>Rainy</Weathers>
                  <Weathers>Windy</Weathers>
                  <Weathers>Stormy</Weathers>
                  <Weathers>Snowy</Weathers>
                </Example>";

            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Example));
            Example example = (Example)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    public enum Weather
    {
        Sunny,
        Cloudy,
        Rainy,
        Windy,
        Stormy,
        Snowy,
    }

    public class Example
    {
        [XmlElement("Weathers")]
        public Weather[] Weathers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This changes the schema provided in the question, which would be a problem, but that turns out to be irrelevant. Notice that if I replace `<Weathers>Windy</Weathers>` with `<Weathe>Windy</Weathe>` to mimic the problem scenario stated in the question then there is similarly no complaint made by the deserialization.

Comment: The schema should have Weathers listed as required to find the error.

Comment: In the question, use of a schema was specifically excluded as a solution.